# Codeception acceptance tests run before browser starts

Tags: selenium, testing, yii2, codeception, acceptance-testing

When I run Codeception tests, sometimes on acceptance tests a browser starts too late, tests do not wait for it to start, and I get errors for tests that passed before a browser start:

> [ConnectionException] Can't connect to Webdriver at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub. Please make sure that Selenium Server or PhantomJS is running.
>
> #1  Codeception\Subscriber\Module->before
>
> #2  D:\path\Yii\basic\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:212
>
> #3  D:\path\Yii\basic\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:44

One time a browser didn't start at all.

My command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K "cd /D D:\path\Yii\basic && vendor\bin\codecept run"
```

**acceptance.suite.yml**:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunProcess:
            - java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="D:/Selenium/geckodriver.exe" "D:/Selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar"
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: https://hotel.localhost/
            browser: chrome
        - Yii2:
            part: orm
            entryScript: index-test.php
            cleanup: false
```

**codeception.yml**:

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    memory_limit: 1024M
    colors: true
modules:
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: 'config/test.php'
            cleanup: false

coverage:
    enabled: true
    whitelist:
        include:
            - models/*
            - controllers/*
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some sleep to RunProcess configuration as documented [here](http://codeception.com/extensions#RunProcess).

> To wait for the process to be launched use sleep option. In this case you need configuration to be specified as object:

```
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunProcess:
            0: java -jar ~/selenium-server.jar
            1: mailcatcher
            sleep: 5 # wait 5 seconds for processes to boot
```

Comment: Thank you! It surprises me though that there is no proper browser start detection and I have to count on empirically chosen value hoping that it would be big enough.

Comment: Replace sleep with: "timeout 300 bash -c 'while [[ \"$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' localhost:4444)\" != '200' ]]; do sleep 5; done' || false"

Comment: This works great, I changed it up to use wait-for-it instead.  eg. 0: java -jar ~/selenium-server.jar  1: wait-for-it 127.0.0.1:4444